# How do I allow access to my Google webapp that writes to a Google Drive Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-authentication

Edit: **Issue Resolved**

After much effort I started from scratch with a very simple script that wrote to a spreadsheet and accessed an external source. I believe my issue was one of not copying the correct deployment links and the sequence of running my tests, /dev vs /exec. Bottom line operator error. Thanks to those who helped.

When publishing the webapp I have selected Execute as Me and Allow access to: Anyone even anonymous.
In Chrome, the webapp works fine when I'm logged in as myself obviously, and writes to the spreadsheet. However if I login under a different email, in one of the tabs, or non logged in, it brings up the Google Request access login screen. Same when I launch it in Chrome on an Android phone.
Interestingly it works fine and writes to the Google Spreadsheet if I run it in a Safari browser without being logged into a Google account. So I must have the permissions correct.
How can I get it to run on any device without the user needed to request access the the Spreadsheet?
Here is the appscript.json manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the published web app url? *Google Request access login screen* If it shows requests access, maybe you're visiting the script file  instead of published app url?

Comment: Yes I am using the web app url.  The one with the /exec on the end. https://script.google.com/macros/s/<<GOOGLEUniqueIDHere>>-/exec

Comment: 1.Although finding a answer to your question is hard it'll be helpful If you add a screenshot of the login page you're seeing and/or a list of redirect urls you're visiting from the /exec url to error page. Network requests tab on the browser dev console may help in getting the data. 2.It might also help if you clear browser cache and trying again.3. Showing your `doGet` script may also help. May be a error occurs and you're redirected to show the error page.3.1 View> Executions will have list of errors if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re publish it with new project version.
1. Click pulbilsh
2. Deploy as web app
3. Change project version to new
4. Publish it